# Cell fracture does not fracture my house model properly

Tags: mesh, add-on

I am trying to apply cell fracture to my house model. The model looks like here:
[image]

When I apply the fracture, the model becomes
[image]

And here are my settings which I am using:
[image]

Does anyone has any idea what's going on?

Comment: That's what generally should happen. What did you want?

Comment: Well, the second picture should be exactly the same as the first one, i.e. on the second case fractures and cracks should be made along the house walls, not changing its geometry! Only when I simulate it should start changing, but the initial geometry should be identical to the original mesh

Comment: If you rendered the geometry in the first picture and then that in the second picture, you shouldn't be able to see a difference. It only looks weird in the _3D Viewport_.

Comment: Well, I am not using rendering, as I only use Blender to export my models back to Unity. So I was kind of trying to reproduce house demolition animation and export every animation frame into separate fbx file to recover demolition sequence. But if geometry is changed, I suspect that it would not be looking as a house anymore...

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your question on a Unity forum or an .fbx file forum? Also, why use Unity? Blender's built in Game Engine can simulate that demolition just fine. There is a two part tutorial on it. Part one can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ).

Comment: It's not about Unity :) It's about geometry in Blender - you can even export all fractured pieces into fbx file and re-import them from that fbx back to Blender. The large artifact chunks, visible in the front wall of the house in the same way as in 2nd picture. It's clearly incorrectly calculated geometries and assigned wrong positions for vertices. I looked at this tutorial several times and at 1:26 I can clearly see that his cup is being fractured correctly (no artifacts). So what's the idea? Can't blender handle something like intersecting surfaces for fracturing or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40500/discussion-between-chanfort-and-shady-puck).